# Using TStringList's AddObject with integers?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tstringlist

Using delphi 7:

- How can I add an integer to the object portion of a stringlist item,
  using `AddObject`?
- How can I retrieve the integer back from a object
  property of stringlist item?
- How do I free all objects and list
  when done?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Q:** `How can i add an integer to the object portion of a stringlist item, using AddObject?`

**A:** Just cast the integer value to [`TObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TObject)

```
List.AddObject('A string',TObject(1));
```

**Q:**`How can a retrieve the integer back from a object property of stringlist item?`

**A:** Cast to integer the Object Value

```
AValue := Integer(List.Objects[i]);
```

**Q:** `How do i free all objects and list when done?`

**A:** You don't need free the object list, because **you are not assigning memory**. so only call the `Free` procedure of the `TStringList`.

Try this sample app

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes,
  SysUtils;


Var
  List : TStringList;
  i    : Integer;
begin
  try
    List:=TStringList.Create;
    try
      //assign the string and some integer values
      List.AddObject('A string',TObject(1));
      List.AddObject('Another string',TObject(100));
      List.AddObject('And another string',TObject(300));

      //Get the integer values back   

       for i:=0 to List.Count - 1 do
         Writeln(Integer(List.Objects[i]));

    finally
      //Free the list  
      List.free;
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: You beat me to it, I was just writing an answer, but I'll upvote yours instead. As a final note to OP, you don't need to explicitly free any objects, except the list, as the TStringList frees its internal list of pointers and you haven't created any objects, only integers that are stored in that list. This is what RRUZ has shown, only freeing the TSTringList.

Comment: @RRUZ - +1 Wow! I think you just solved a major issue for me that I have been trying to figure out. I like to use ID/Value pairs for database lookup values. So if I understand the above corrrectly I can display the List.Strings[i] (the value part) in a dropdown and use the associated Integer(List.Objects[i]) as the ForeignKey Id in the database.

Comment: @IElite, I've used a similar trick to store a list of floating point values where precision and dynamic range is not crucial ( the Delphi `single` type is 4 bytes and can be typecast to a pointer).  You can also use a TList if there are no strings and the integers/floats are all you want to store.