# Can TStringList.Sort return sorted indexes?

Tags: pascal, freepascal, fpc

Using TStringList.Sort to sort a collection of strings in free pascal, I need to remember the initial order. Is there a possibility to return the sorted indexes?
If not, how can this be done efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the object property to store the original index of the item.

So you can insert your items in this way

```
SL.AddObject('Item 1', TObject(SL.Count));
SL.AddObject('Item 2', TObject(SL.Count));
```

and retrieve the original index after sort the TStringList

```
   Index := Integer(SL.Objects[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you. After posting the question I found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7237738/1165818) and thought it might work for me, it is the same as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but since strings are copy on write, you can simply assign the tstringlist to a second tstringlist using

```
   t2.assign(t1);
```

This won't duplicate the strings. Due to the copy on write behaviour, tstringlist is like an index for strings.